# Transfer files from linux (of linuxdeploy in android) to android (in which linuxdeploy is installed)

Tags: linux, file-copy, file-transfer, file-manager

I am using Linux on my Android phone via use of Linux deploy.

I have some files in `/root/android/` - folder of that linux partition.

And I want one of those files to move to my `/storage/sdcard1/` - folder of my android.

Now the thing is all data of that linux file is saved in `linux.img` in `sdcard1`.

I literally have no way to move that file from "linux root" to "android sdcard".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the ans which is at number 3:::
**1-by uploading-downloading**

I went further to check if any online upload-download site supports use of command line,  and came across 
**https://transfer.sh** site. Using it I transfered my file by uploading and downloading.

First upload your file to that site using below command after moving to that folder which contains file.

```
curl --upload-file https://transfer.sh/yourfilename
```

When you execute this command , it will give you a new URL (e.g. https://transfer.sh/lPTH/yourfilename) using which u can download ur file..

To download your file use following command.

```
curl "https://transfer.sh/lPTH/yourfilename" -o -k yourfilename
```

(Replace URL in "" with whtever url you get by uploading)
Another way is just open any browser and open URL which you get by uploading.

Enjoy.

**2- using usb**

I still cant mount my sdcard(which is in) but i found way(actually command) to mount usb..
Use otg cable and connect usb with yout phone.
Then.

Use command "lsusb" to check if linux can detect your usb.

Use "blkid" command to check location of your usb(in my case it was /dev/block/sda), which normally would be somewhere in dev folder, also note down partition type of your usb(normally vfat) cause we will need it in mounting command.

Now to mount your usb in linux use this command.

```
mount -t vfat /dev/block/sda /mnt
```

It will mount your usb to /mnt folder from there you can transfer your things. To check size and left space use "df -h".

To unmount.:

```
umount /dev/block/sda
```

**3-mount sdcard**

Just like number 2, i found my sdcard at

```
/dev/block/mmcblk1p1
```

Location, using command 
**"blkid"**..

So mount it (whtever ur sdcard location is) to /mnt and exchange data..

Enjoy..

Answer (score 0):

you can use **file server** (oython)
just run

```
sudo python -m SimpleHTTPServer 88
```

and then go to your anbox and open **webView Browser**
open http://192.168.1.x:88

> note : replace above ip with your internal ip

now, You can download any thing from your computer to your anbox

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is go to your Linux Deploy App Settings and mount directory

```
/storage/sdcard1/
```

or which ever Android directory you want to view from VNC. Install `sudo dnf install thunar`
(Fedora) or `sudo apt-get install thunar`
For Debian or Ubuntu. Go to `cd ../../`
directory via terminal and type `dir`
There you can view and access your external sdcard via Linux Deploy App. You can as well use downloaded file manager(Thunar) to do the transfer.

Another good option is to simply use ftp client like Filezilla on Linux and ftp server App on Android.